# Wave with a source on the half-line

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Problem:

$u_{tt} - c^2u_{xx}=f(x,t) \quad 0<x<\infty, t>0$

$u(x,0) = 0, u_t (x,0) = 0 \quad (for \quad all\quad 0<x<\infty)$

$u(0,t)=0 \quad (for \quad all\quad t>0)$

Ok so on the half-line this is a nonhomo. wave equation, with homo. IC and homo. Dirichelt boundary conditions. c>0 is a constant, f is continuous.

So solving this and sketching the domain of integration, as well as verifying that the BC is satisfied I started using this:

For region $0<ct<x$ I have solution:

$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2c} \iint_\Delta f$

For region $0<x<ct$ I have solution:

$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2c} \iint_D f$

I am not sure what exactly the solution to this is. Is this the final answer?

What is the difference between $\Delta$ and D?

I just extrapolated from a worked out problem - so not sure if this is even correct. Please help!

Also what is the domain of integration sketched out?

UPDATE:

I got that D is the domain of dominance?

and $\Delta$ is characteristics?

Please help trying to solve this one!!

Comment: Try using Duhamel's principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem was posed on the entire line, the solution would be 
$$
u(x,t) =\frac{1}{2c}\iint_\Delta f \tag{1}
$$
where $\Delta$ is the triangle with vertices $(x,t)$, $(x-ct,0)$ and $(x+ct,0)$. It may be called the  domain of dependence, or the characteristic triangle, or something else.

[image: triangle]

In the region $x\ge ct$ this is exactly what you get, since the boundary effect is not felt there.

One way to handle the boundary condition  is to use reflection: extend $f$ to the region $x<0$ by $f(-x,t) = -f(x,t)$. The reason for doing this is that the solution with odd source function $f$ will vanish when $x=0$: indeed, the integral in (1) is zero because the half $x<0$ cancels out the by symmetry.

[image: symmetry]

What if $0<x<ct$? Then a part of the triangle $\Delta$ lies in the reflected territory, which cancels out a chunk of the positive part. We can call what's left $D$:  so, 
$$
u(x,t) =\frac{1}{2c}\iint_D f 
$$

[image: part]

The domain $D$ can be also described in inequalities: $$D=\{(y,s): |x-c(t-s)|\le y\le x+c(t-s)\}$$ but this hardly makes its shape clear than a picture.

Comment: So u(x,t) is a peicesise? If x>=ct we get the intregal with the triangle, and i if 0<x<ct we get the one with the d?

Comment: Yes, when you solve wave equation on half-line, the solution is usually piecewise.

Comment: Just to be crystal clear, to answer the question fully - the below is the full final answer?

Comment: Also How can I verify the BC are met?

Answer (score 0):

$u(x,t) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{lr}
    \frac{1}{2c}\iint_\Delta f \tag{1} &  x \ge ct\\
    \frac{1}{2c}\iint_D f  & \quad 0 < x< ct
  \end{array}
\right.
$

With domain being:

[image: part]
$ \quad$

Just want to be crystal clear what the answer is here.